# Set of non-units in non-commutative ring

Tags: ring-theory

I consider the question:

> In a non-commutative ring $R$ with $1$, is the union of maximal left ideals equals the set of non-units?

If $x$ is non-unit then it can happen that $yx=1$ for some $y$ but $xz\neq 1$ for any $z$. Hence, it may be that although $x$ is non-unit, the left ideal generated by $x$ could be whole ring.

Conversely, if $x$ is in the union of maximal left ideals then $x$ will not be unit, since multiplying to $x$ by any element will land in (proper) ideal and it will never be $1$.

So my conclusion is (Union of maximal left ideals) $\subseteq$ (set of non-units) but not conversely. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.

Example: consider $R$ the endomorphism ring of a vector space with a countable basis $\{e_0,e_1,e_2,\dotsc\}$; define $f(e_k)=e_{k+1}$. Then $f$ is left invertible via the map $g(e_{k+1})=e_k$ and $g(e_0)=0$, but not right invertible because it's not surjective.

Thus we have a nonunit that is not in the union of the maximal left ideals, because $Rf=R$.

However, an element that belongs to a maximal left ideal cannot be a unit.